# Python iterative loop

Tags: python, loops, syntax, iteration

I'm trying to iterate through a search list, I've written it like I would in C but I want to re-write this more pythonic.

I've been trying with `enumerate` but I can't seem to get it to work, It is searching lines of data for key-words which are saved in an array called strings, can someone show me or explain the correct python syntax please.

thanks

```
for line in f:
    jd = json.loads(line)
    N=0
    while N<=(len(strings)-1):
        if findWholeWord(strings[N])(line) != None:
            print (jd['user_id'], jd['text'])
            break
        N=N+1
```

Comment: Please, provide the example input and expected output for your problem. You could also use `for` loop, instead of `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no need to use `enumerate` here. Just iterate over `strings` directly:

```
for s in strings:
    if findWholeWord(s)(line) != None:
        print (jd['user_id'], jd['text'])
        break
```

If you also need the index variable `n`, then use `enumerate`:

```
for n, s in enumerate(strings):
    if findWholeWord(s)(line) != None:
        # do something with n here?
        print (jd['user_id'], jd['text'])
        break
```

But since you `break` after the first match anyway, you could probably also use the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) builtin:

```
if any(findWholeWord(s)(line) != None for s in strings):
    jd = json.loads(line)
    print (jd['user_id'], jd['text'])
```

Also, as pointed out in [@Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30570134/1639625), you can probably improve the performance of the check by turning either `strings` or `line` into a `set` of words and then just using the `in` operator to check whether some word from the one set is in the other. But this is difficult to tell without knowing what exactly `findWholeWord` is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Make strings a set instead of an array (for performance, won't change functionality)

```
strings = set(strings)
```

I don't know what findWholeWord(strings[N])(line) is meant to do. But I'm guessing it's something like this:

```
jd = json.loads(s)
## json.loads needs to be used instead json.load since 's' will be a STRING

if any(w in strings for w in tokenize(line)):
    print (jd['user_id'], jd['text'])
```

I'm guessing findWholeWords gets whole words from the line and checks them against your set of strings. If so, you could use a proper tokenizer (look at NLTK) or just use:

```
def tokenize(line):
  return line.split(' ')
```